# windows phone 8 emulator slow internet connection

Tags: cordova, internet-explorer-10, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

I'm developing a web app for windows phone 8 using cordova/phonegap.

It's happening that some parts of my app take up to 8 minutes to load, so I think that the problem is that internet connection somehow is not working well.

How can I know if internet connection is not working well and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to test if internet connection is slow is using IE on Emulator and see if you see delay in internet access. If yes, you can try some of the suggestions described in the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx